# How to modified dataset

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working with a dataset like this, where the values of 'country name' are repeat several time, and 'Indicator name' to.

[image]

I want to create a new dataset with its columns are like that

```
Year  CountryName IndicatorName1 IndicatorName2 ... IndicatorNameX
2000.  USA.       value1.        value2.            valueX
2000.  Canada.    value1.        value2.            valueX    
2001.  USA.       value1.        value2.            valueX
2001.  Canada.    value1.        value2.            valueX
```

it is possible to do that??

Thanks in advances!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I pivot a dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-can-i-pivot-a-dataframe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pivot` as suggested by @Chris but you can also try:

```
out = df.set_index(['Country Name', 'Indicator Name']).unstack('Country Name').T \
        .rename_axis(index=['Year', 'Country'], columns=None).reset_index()
print(out)

# Output
   Year Country  IndicatorName1  IndicatorName2
0  2000  France               1               3
1  2000   Italy               2               4
2  2001  France               5               7
3  2001   Italy               6               8
```

Setup a [Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/15239951) / [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

```
data = {'Country Name': ['France', 'Italy', 'France', 'Italy'],
        'Indicator Name': ['IndicatorName1', 'IndicatorName1', 
                           'IndicatorName2', 'IndicatorName2'],
        2000: [1, 2, 3, 4],
        2001: [5, 6, 7, 8]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

# Output
  Country Name  Indicator Name  2000  2001
0       France  IndicatorName1     1     5
1        Italy  IndicatorName1     2     6
2       France  IndicatorName2     3     7
3        Italy  IndicatorName2     4     8
```